# Find needed capacitance of charged capacitor with constant power load

Tags: capacitance, time-constant

I would like to discuss the circuit depicted in the screenshot of a simulation in LTspice. Let's assume there is a capacitor charged to `V0 = 25 V` that is connected to a load that drains a constant power of `P = 10 W`.

The capacitor should supply that power over a period of `T = 100 ms`. During this period the voltage is allowed to drop from `25 V` to `15 V`.

From the simulation, I found a value for the capacitance of `C = 5 mF`. I am wondering how to calculate that value (ideally also for additionally considering the capacitor's ESR) because standard equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) always assume a constant time constant. However, in my case, the constant power load leads to a time-dependent load resistance of `R(t) = Vc(t)^2 / P`, and thus to a time-dependent time constant `tau(t) = R(t) C`.

[image: simulation]

Comment: I rolled back your edit because the question post is neither for answers, nor for asking additional questions. Please ask additional questions in a separate question post.

Comment: Ok thanks, my fault ...

Comment: No problem.....

Comment: Anyway, that's a ~trivial addition; see my edit.  As for time constant, there is no such parameter in the system, and I would suggest ignoring it as meaningless here. If you must, the dynamic resistance r = dV/dI can be calculated from the instantaneous V(I) relationship.  I'm not sure the resulting tau has much meaning, say if we integrate it over time (anyway, it's only going to give the same result with extra steps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the answer using calculus, consider the capacitor equation:

$$ I = C \frac{dV}{dt} $$

and the load curve,

$$ I = \frac{P}{V} $$

Equate them, and rearrange:

$$ C \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{P}{V} $$
Although we get a differential equation, we rearrange to find it's implicitly integrable without any hackery:
$$ C dV = \frac{P}{V} dt $$
$$ \int_{V_\textrm{start}}^{V_\textrm{final}} V dV = \int_{t_\textrm{start}}^{t_\textrm{final}} \frac{P}{C} dt $$
C and P are constants, so can be brought outside the integrals, or moved between sides, as needed.
$$ \left[ \frac{V^2}{2} \right]_{V_\textrm{final}}^{V_\textrm{start}} = \frac{P}{C} \left( t_\textrm{final} - t_\textrm{start} \right) $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left({V_\textrm{start}}^2 - {V_\textrm{final}}^2\right) = \frac{P}{C} \Delta t $$
Rearranging finally,
$$ C = \frac{2 P \Delta t}{ {V_\textrm{start}}^2 - {V_\textrm{final}}^2} $$

(Note that the start and end times have been reduced to a change in time, but the difference of squares of voltage mean they can't be written in the same way.)

Which gives the same answer as equating the start and final energy in the capacitor; as it must, as capacitance is a conservative element and a thermodynamic sort of method (i.e. an energy argument at instants in time, rather than considering the whole continuous path between them) will produce the same result.

Also note, this solution applies for positive real variables and V<sub>start</sub> > V<sub>final</sub>.  Negative power and time would be sensible as giving power back (which could be a kind of hold-up capacity for a regenerative braking system, I suppose), or swapping the order of voltages implying some strange capacitance that gains voltage as energy is drawn from it (a negative capacitance).

We can rearrange this expression for voltage as a function of time,
$$ V(t)^2 = {V_i}^2 - \frac{2 P t}{ C } $$
$$ V(t) = \sqrt{ {V_i}^2 - \frac{2 P t}{ C } } $$
using \$V_i\$ as the initial voltage, for some constant power P load and voltage falling as time \$t \ge 0\$ advances.  We take the positive square-root, and note that the result becomes complex for \$t > \frac{{V_i}^2 C}{2 P}\$ as this is a singularity point (indeed, as the capacitor runs completely out of energy, the rate of voltage becomes infinitely downward; a cusp).  Values beyond the actual cutoff voltage of a load (nothing can draw up to infinite current at down to zero voltage) aren't meaningful, but it's neat that the math extends all the way to zero.

For a handy implementation, I have this calculator on my website: [Power Supply Hold-up Time | Calculators | Seven Transistor Labs, LLC](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Calc/PSHoldUp.html#cp)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Tim! I will now try to solve the same while considering the additional series resistance R_esr of the capacitor...

Answer (score 5):

> I am wondering how to calculate that value

Without using calculus, you could use the formula for the energy in a capacitor:

$$E = \frac{CV^2}{2}$$

Note that that I am using E here for energy and not electric field.

If the constant power is 10 W, and the duration is 100 ms, the total energy change is 10 W x 0.1 s = 1 J.

The voltage drops from 25 V down to 15 V. So,

$$\frac{C\times 25^2}{2} - \frac{C\times 15^2}{2} = 1$$

So
$$\frac{C\times 625}{2} - \frac{C\times 225}{2} = 1$$

$$\frac{C \times 400}{2} = 1$$

So

$$C = \frac{2}{400} = 0.005 F = 5 mF$$

Answer (score 2):

10 watts is 10 joules per second and, over 0.1 seconds that's an energy loss of 1 joule. So, if your 5 mF capacitor is correct in value, when charged to 25 volts, it should possess an energy of: -

$$W\text{ (energy)} = \dfrac{C\cdot V^2}{2} = 1.5625\text{ joules}$$

If you remove 1 joule (leaving you with 0.5625 joules stored) and, did the reverse calculation to find voltage, you will find it equals 15 volts. I did this reverse calculation and can confirm that.

I'm sure you can find a more elegant formula compared to my two-pronged approach.